# Config information on ancient 16-bit Multi I/O card

Tags: hardware, ibm-pc

I need to build a retro machine so that I can access an HDD that required manual input of BIOS parameters. (Yes, I have that information.)

The only ID I can find is ES1O/4A 280695 which yields nothing useful in searches, apart from this group.

The information on the SMC chip is:
fdc37c654Qf
B9504-B243
6J74560-2A
So I'm guessing, by fdc, that it only cares about the floppy drive(s).

[image: ES1O_4A 280695]

Most notable features are that the 10-pin connectors are vertical, 10 by 3 pin config block under the IDE connector, and the massive 8 by 5 pin IRQ block.

I'm guessing that the serial ports are functionally configured from "whenever", but I need to disable drive ports to avoid conflict with mobo ports.

Although the primary purpose of this build is data recovery from HDD that can't be recognised through a USB converter, it will also be running my music training software which won't function on anything higher than 486.

[image: ES1O_4A 280695 Back]

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a photo of the back of the card?

Comment: Alternatively, you could look through [the multi-I/O cards on TULARC](https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/io-cards/index.html) and see if yours is described there.

Comment: Is there anything written on the config block? I cannot make it out in the photo. Also try to carefully remove some of the bridges to see if there's writing. For the IRQ block, my guess would be you can assign three IRQs (upper, middle, lower row) by bridges similar to the ones shown in the photo. The IDE IRQ is in a different block, as written. Also, the IDE connector definitely needs a bigger chip somewhere to drive it. Either on the backside, or the SMC does that, too.

Comment: What info exactly are you looking for? My guess is that the SMC chip handles most/all the functions, not just floppy. The IDE IRQ jumper under the smc chip specifies which IRQ (14 or 15) the single IDE port uses. The 5x8 IRQ jumper specifies which IRQs most/all of the other functions use.  The 3x10 jumper block near top middle may be responsible for enabling/disabling each function. The lower right DMA jumper block likely sets the DMA channel for the IDE controller. Not sure about the FDD jumper block.

Comment: From wiki, the 4 "standard" PC serial ports are typically defined as:

    COM1: I/O port 0x3F8, IRQ 4 //
    COM2: I/O port 0x2F8, IRQ 3 //
    COM3: I/O port 0x3E8, IRQ 4 //
    COM4: I/O port 0x2E8, IRQ 3 // so each of the 2 serial ports on this board, if enabled, need to have both an I/O port and an IRQ assigned to them.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Well from the photo, the "IDE" and "FDD" pin blocks look like they are both unjumpered, so maybe that's enough to disable all the drive ports.

Comment: @Armand The DMA block is for the parallel port in ECP mode, not floppy. Floppy DMA is on DMA2 (secondary floppy controllers on different resources are not well-supported), and the jumper block doesn't provide DMA2.

Comment: @dirkt you don't need anything complicated to drive an IDE port. The main idea of IDE is that it just forwards ISA cycles to the hard drive, which has the actual controller ("drive electronics") integrated to the drive. *Usually* you buffer the low 8 bits of the ISA bus, but you might even get away without that. On this card, U2 might be the IDE data buffer.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher I think you misunderstood - I wrote that the DMA block is for the IDE controller (hard drive); for IBM PCs, DMA3 was the default for the IDE, but DMA1 could be used instead. If this board was used for the primary/only IDE controller, it would be set to DMA3; if it was a 2nd IDE controller in the system, it would be set to DMA1.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Looking at the SMC chip datasheet, it only has an original PC type parallel port, not the AT bidirectional or the later EPP or ECP port. Does it even use a DMA channel?

Comment: @Armand Indeed, you are right. The SMC chip does not provide ECP, so no parallel port DMA. 8-bit DMA (DMA 1 or DMA 3) is of no use for 16-bit AT IDE (what we know as IDE today), but it might be used for 8-bit XT IDE. The SMC '653/'654 datasheet cites an XT mode that can use DMA, but it seems the XT mode can only be enabled on the soft-configured '653, not on the jumper-configured '654. That card keeps a mystery.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt A photo of the back would only reveal the identifiers already supplied. Thanks for the links

Comment: @Treknology it would give more details on the layout of the card too.

Comment: @Armand It's my intention to disable everything except both COM ports and LPT. I want both drives and game port gone.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher The FDD block is in the upper left, but only numbered pins 1-6.

Comment: No one has noticed the jumper on lower right behind LPT connector. 

I'm guessing that the board was originally configured with everything working, so I'm really attempting _intelligently targeted_ sabotage.

It's lack of data on those huge jumper panels that is so frustrating.

Sorry if I've misdirect comments. My brain is fried.

@StephenKitt Photo added.

Comment: @Armand Back to ECP - it is extremely likely that the PCB is designed to accomodate the FDC37C666, which supports ECP DMA and has 12 configuration jumpers, 2 of them setting "FDC stuff". The card shown here is a low-cost edition of that card equipped with the "last-year I/O controller model available at a discount". So some of the jumpers *just don't serve any useful purpose*.

Answer (score 6):

A bit of googling finds that SMC is "Standard Microsystems Corporation", apparently got renamed at one time to SMSC and finally to "Microchip".

The FDC37C654 is a Super-I/O chip with a floppy disk controller, hard disk controller,  two serial ports, and a parallel port. The datasheet can be found e.g. [here](http://13.124.15.139/pdf/download.php?id=4d063b708d8d68efa9bd2203f953c0d246ca90&type=O&term=FDC37) from [this page](http://13.124.15.139/FDC37-datasheet.html) (not sure how stable this link is).

Configuration pins are

```
80/81  PCF0/1  Parallel Port Configuration (disable, 3BCH, 378H, 278H)
24/23  SICF0/1  Primary Serial Port Configuration (disable, 3E8H, 2F8H, 3F8H)
91/93  S2CFO/1  Secondary Serial Port Configuration (disable, 2E8H, 3F8H, 2F8H)
83  IDECF  IDE Configuration (disable, enable)
89  TDCCF  Floppy Disk Controller (disable, enable)
```

I would assume these correspond to 8 of the 10 positions in the config header at the top. If you can read the printing around the config header (remove the bridges if necessary), that should probably identify which is which.

If there's nothing printed on the board, you could try tracing the connections, or trial and error (pick a setting, try to access serial port etc.)

Interrupt pins are:

```
38 PSPIRQ  Source of Primary Serial Port Interrupt (IRQ3 or IRQ4)
37 SSPIRQ  Source of Secondary Serial Port Interrupt (IRQ3 or IRQ4)
49 FINTR   Floppy Interrupt 
39 PINTR   Parallel Port Interrupt
```

And I'd assume some of these are part of the IRQ header. I don't see any Harddisk IRQ pin. Possibly the Floppy Interrupt is both for Floppy and Harddisk? Or just labelled "IDE"?

The Harddisk/Floppy DMA is probably available at the DMA config block, but I don't understand the details.

---

After seeing the photo of the backside: The configuration block on the top routes the middle pins ("2" row) to the resistors directly below, and then from the resistors to the chip on the front side. This means the "1" and "3" row have a constant voltage, representing 0 and 1, and you can figure out which is which by following the traces on the front, if there's nothing else written on the PCB around the configuration block that's not visible in the first picture.

Once you've identified which pin the jumpers go to, the above table will give you the settings to enable and disable the various parts (disabling is two 0 bits).

As the standard serial port configuration is 3F8H and 2F8H, a first guess is that serial ports are enabled in this configuration (because motherboard serials very rare). So then the "1" row means 1, the "3" row means 0. Try moving all jumpers from the top to the bottom, see if the conflicts are gone.

This will also change the two additional jumpers that do not know what they are good for (and I cannot see the front side well enough to trace), so do this at your own risk.

Comment: If you have a multimeter it would be a simple matter to buzz out the pins in continuity mode to see what goes where.

Comment: The hard disk/IDE IRQ is set in the jumper block at bottom left - choices are IRQ 14 or 15. The hard disk/IDE DMA is set to DMA1 or 3 in the DMA jumper block at bottom center.

Comment: There's also a game port, so some config pins should correspond to that.

Comment: You don't see a harddisk IRQ pin, because the hard disk IRQ is routed straight from the IDE conntector to the ISA bus. In this card, not completely straight, because there is a jumper that can choose between IRQ14 or IRQ15. The Super-I/O-Chip doesn't care about anything of the hard disk interface except for telling the hard drive that currently the I/O range of the hard drive is accessed. The remaining stuff is directly connected between the IDE connector and the ISA connector.

Comment: Counting the chips on the card, there are 5 level translator chips (2*1488, 3*1489) for the serial ports, the 74LS367 and (there has to be, can't read it) an NE556 for the game port. That's it. So no kind of buffering the data or address lines for the IDE port. That's the cheapest possible design.

Comment: This extremely small card http://www.amoretro.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/cd-rom_isa_controller_audio_out.jpg is actually a *better* IDE interface than the one is the card in this thread, because it buffers IOW/IOR in the 74LS08, and it buffers the low 8 ISA data lines in the 74LS245.

Answer (score 5):

This card is a low-cost model. The PCB is actually designed to take the more modern FDC37C666 chip, but on the card shown in the original post, the older (but mostly compatible) FDC37C654 is equipped instead. The two jumpers labelled FDD (JP5 and JP6) are most likely:

- FACF - pin 26 - not a configuration pin on the '654. Position doesn't matter
- FDCCF - pin 89 - floppy disk enable (1-2)/disable(2-3)

The block of 10 jumpers (JP7-JP16) contains (order guessed according to hints from the visible traces. JP8, JP11, JP12 are clearly identified)

- JP7: IDECF - pin 83 - hard disk enable (1-2)/disable(2-3)
- JP8: IDEACF - pin 25 - not a configuration pin on the '654. Position doesn't matter
- JP9: ECPEN - pin 94 - not a configuration pin on the '654. Position doesn't matter
- JP10: PADCF - pin 58 - not a configuration pin on the '654. Position doesn't matter
- JP11: PCF1 - pin 81 - parallel port base address
- JP12: PCF0 - pin 79 - parallel port base address
- S1CF0/S1CF1 24/23 - first serial port base address
- S2CF0/S2CF1 91/93 - second serial port base address

JP11/JP12: 1-2/1-2 = 278 ("LPT2"); 1-2/2-3 = 378 ("LPT1"); 2-3/1-2 = 3BC (MDA compatible); 2-3/2-3 = disable

Serial port 1: 1-2/1-2 = 3F8 ("COM1"); 1-2/2-3 = 2F8 ("COM2"); 2-3/1-2 = 3E8 ("COM3"); 2-3/2-3 = disabled.
Serial port 2: 1-2/1-2 = 2F8 ("COM2"); 1-2/2-3 = 3F8 ("COM1"); 2-3/1-2 = 2E8 ("COM4"); 2-3/2-3 = disabled.

*Do not plug any DMA jumpers*. Those signals are only valid in ECP mode of the '666 controller. They serve a different function on the '654, and may cause your computer to misbehave if some software erroneously tries to access a third or fourth floppy drive.

The jumper next to the parallel port can disable two of the six signals generated by U11. Most likely, U11 is part of the game port interface, and drives game port input to the ISA bus. With U11 in the top position (as on the photo), U11 drives only four bits (2 axes, 2 buttons). With U11 in the bottom position, U11 drives six bits, probably two extra buttons for joysticks with actual 4 buttons or special functions like a coolie hat. There seems to be no way to disable the game port completely.

Comment: Your deductions make a lot of sense. Using "last year's model" parts is a good way to clear out older chips and provide a cheaper entry-level product. Thanks for your effort on this.